# BigQuery Avro load job with useAvroLogicalTypes incorrect field types

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I'm using node.js to:

- create an Avro file using the `avsc` NPM package
- upload to GCS using the `@google-cloud/storage` NPM package
- call the BQ API using the `@google-cloud/bigquery` NPM package to load the Avro from GCS to BQ

My problem is that even if I set `useAvroLogicalTypes` when I create the load job, my date data is never correctly created as `TIMESTAMP` in BQ, always `INTEGER` - [which should be the normal behavior](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types) when `useAvroLogicalTypes` is **NOT** set.

According to the same docs, if `timestamp-millis` is set in the Avro schema definition, it should load as `TIMESTAMP`.

My configuration:

### Avro schema

```
{
      "name": "metadata",
      "type": {
        "name": "metadata",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "creationTime",
            "type": "long",
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
          },
          {
            "name": "lastActivity",
            "type": ["null", "long"],
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
          },
          {
            "name": "deletionTime",
            "type": ["null", "long"],
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
          },
          {
            "name": "lastSignInTime",
            "type": ["null", "long"],
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

### Create load job

```
const metadata = {
  sourceFormat: 'AVRO',
  useAvroLogicalTypes: true
}
```

The only way I could get it work is by specifying the scema again in the metadata var for the load job. My question is, isn't the whole point of specifying the Avro schema and turning on `useAvroLogicalTypes` to avoid having to explicitly spec the schema again the the load job metadata?

### Working setup

```
const metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'AVRO',
    useAvroLogicalTypes: true,
    schema: {
      fields: [
        ...otherFields,
        {
          name: 'metadata',
          type: 'STRUCT',
          mode: 'REQUIRED',
          fields: [
            { name: 'creationTime', type: 'TIMESTAMP', mode: 'REQUIRED' },
            { name: 'lastActivity', type: 'TIMESTAMP', mode: 'NULLABLE' },
            { name: 'deletionTime', type: 'TIMESTAMP', mode: 'NULLABLE' },
            { name: 'lastSignInTime', type: 'TIMESTAMP', mode: 'NULLABLE' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question about specifying the Avro schema during creating the load job. It is possible to omit schema property, which is the schema for the destination table:

> The schema can be omitted if the destination table already exists, or if you're loading data from Google Cloud Datastore.

If you want to read more about it, please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad.FIELDS.schema).

In addition, you can also take a look to the [--autodetect flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local) which replaces the schema definition.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, you are right, I did not notice or understand that information correctly. I wanna especially thank you for joining StackOverflow to help me ! :) Happy new year!